# Need to listing user input in python

Tags: python

I need help figuring out how to turn a simple user input like

```
a = input('Enternumber: ')
```

and if the user was to input say...

```
hello bob Jeff Lexi Ava
```

How am I supposed to have the computer turn that into a list like,

```
hello

bob

Jeff

Lexi

Ava
```

If someone has the code could they please explain what they are doing. *This is python

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to just cut the string on spaces, then print one word per line. What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` method.

```
my_string = 'hello bob Jeff Lexi Ava'

print(my_string.split())  # ['hello', 'bob', 'Jeff', 'Lexi', 'Ava']
```

To print each on a line:

```
for word in my_string:
    print(word)
```